# libssh2_config.h not created when installing libssh2

Tags: c++, ubuntu, libssh2

The title more or less describes the problem I'm having on my Ubuntu box.
I followed the following steps in installing libssh2, as given in the instructions:

./configure
make
make check (all 3 tests passed)
sudo make install (I have to use sudo due to permissions)

I then try to use some of the examples given in libssh2 page and they all have the following:

```
#include "libssh2_config.h"
```

Which isn't found. The following 3 files are created in usr/local/include:

```
libssh2.h
libssh2_publickey.h
libssh2_sftp.h
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I still can't figure out why the file isn't created, but it is not really necessary, since removing the following #ifdefs:

```
#ifdef HAVE_WINDOWS_H
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_WINSOCK2_H
#include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_ARPA_INET_H
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
```

and simply replacing (on linux) with:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

as well as removing the rest of #ifdefs in the code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

libssh2_config.h is in the example dir, you need to copy into your projects.

Comment: This would be better posted as a comment. Have you read the [how to answer guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Comment: No, it is not always in the example directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are libssh2_config.h files in the win32 dir, the vms dir and the os400 dir. You need to copy one of these into your projects.